# Calculating column value using join and updating in the table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables namely **foo** and **bar**

```
Table :foo
col1  col2  col3   col4
4      6      1      a
5      2      1      b
3      8      2      c

Table: bar
colA                 colB                colC
(col1/col3)          (col2/col3)          a
.                       .                 b
.                       .                 c
.                       .                 d
```

I want to  update the table **bar** using above calculation  and join it in the **bar** table to achieve the result, colC in **bar**  and col4 in **foo** are common to use joinhow should I go for .Any help would be much appreciated.
so my resulting **bar** table would be like

```
colA                       colB        
4(col1/col3)             6(col2/col3)
5(col1/col3)             2(col2/col3)
0.5(col1/col3)           4(col2/col3)
```

Comment: Do you want to `update` or `insert` into `bar` table? Show your full `create table codes` and expected result based on these data.

Comment: Please show the results you would like to get.  If you are looking for generic parsing and execution, then SQL is probably not the right tool.

Comment: @1000111 I want to update the column colA & colB of table bar.

Comment: Then how the two tables are related? Define the relationship. Post the `table structure code` and your expected result based on some valid data.

Comment: What does the `bar` table contain before your expected update operation? @Deepesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to insert into `bar`:

```
insert into bar(colA, colB)
    select col1 / col3, col2 / col3
    from foo;
```

This seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question; there are no keys for joining the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
    INSERT INTO 
            bar 
    SELECT 
            (col1/col3),(col2/col3)
    FROM 
            foo
```